# I have converted PCA related matlab code into python code, how may i correct the last line code of python?

Tags: python, matlab, pycharm

I have made PCA related code in python, which is converted from Matlab code to python code but last line code is not working.

how may I correct it?

MatLAB Code:

```
    [coeff,score,~,~,explained] = pca(train);            
    sm = 0;
    no_components = 0;
    for k = 1:size(explained,1)
        sm = sm+explained(k);
        if sm <= 99.4029
           no_components= no_components+1;
        end
    end
    m = mean(train,1);
    mat1 = score(:,1:no_components);
```

Python Code:

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.score

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import os
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
    [x,y] = trainData.shape

    pca = PCA(n_components=(x-1))
    varPca = pca.fit(trainData)

    explainedVariance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_*100

    sm = 0
    no_components = 0
    for k in range(0, x-1):
        sm = sm+explainedVariance[k]
        if sm <= 99.4029:
            no_components= no_components+1
    print(no_components)

    m = trainData.mean()
    print(m)
    mat1 = score(trainData[:,0:no_components])
```

Here score function is not performing well.

How may I correct it?

Comment: What do you mean by not performing well?

Comment: reflecting some error as : NameError: name 'score' is not defined

Comment: score function is not running

Comment: Yes, the function `score()` is not defined anywhere. Your program cannot guess what you want to do...

Comment: but i am using the score function present into this link:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.score

Comment: you can compare score variable of matlab present into this link:  https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html

Comment: how may I convert    mat1 = score(:,1:no_components);      matlab code to python, focus on that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`score` is the method of the class `PCA()`. As such it can only be called on a `PCA()` object.

In your case `pca` is an object of the class `PCA()`. Therefore you can call `pca.score()`.

However, calling `score()` by itself supposes that that is a function `score()` defined somewhere, which is not the case. This is why you get a `NameError`.

Comment: ok it works but another error occurs when i used it as mat1 = pca.score(trainData[:,0:no_components]).

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (738,404) (40000,)

Comment: Can you check the shape of the argument you pass in the `score` function? It should be similar to what the documentation indicates: `X : array, shape(n_samples, n_features)`

Comment: That means you have only 1 feature!? This does not make much sense. For the sake of testing things out do `pca.score(trainData)`